# Не удается получить файл с удаленного сервера

Tags: php

Пример скрипта:

```
<?
$files = [
    [
        'url' => 'https://cs1-41v4.vk-cdn.net/p20/b5e45ecd84ac65.mp3?extra=vfY-bFvuPvDSEnlZMYWKBYT6GiwNKWi5VgzqRLIiXnK-6EeYaUg-ypaXG4d4eoVtDafoQTdpsp9gFof2T2nXPztSlKdQ46o,262',
        'name' => '2 Brothers On The 4th Floor - Dreams.mp3'
    ], [
        'url' => 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png',
        'name' => 'googlelogo.png'
    ]
];
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$files[1]['name']);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
echo file_get_contents($files[1]['url']);
```

В случае с `$files[1]` файл успешно скачивается и переименовывается, но при `$files[0]` возникает ошибка: "*HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found*", а если перейти по ссылке то файл доступен.

Пробовал использовать Curl, ответ в заголовке получал: "**302 Found**" и ссылку на 404 страницу, заголовок запроса *User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"* никак не повлиял.

Сервер из ссылки `$files[0]['url']` получается уже знает что файл запрашивает не браузер.

Answer (score 1):

> но при $files[0], возникает ошибка:

запятая не нужна

> Побывал

Проб**о**вал. Там никогда не было "ы".

Ваша проблема в том, что заголовок content-disposition содержит в себе неэкранированные пробелы, и, с точки зрения HTTP и браузера, неправильно сформирован:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=2 Brothers On The 4th Floor - Dreams.mp3');
```

В данном случае получается, что filename соответствует двум, а дальше идет еще куча параметров.

Это - одно из больных мест веба, потому что до сих пор существуют слегка различные стандарты для кодирования имен файлов и разрешения использования non-ascii символов в них. Если долго, то нужно читать [RFC5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987), если кратко - возьмите название файла в кавычки:

```
header(sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="%s"', $files[1]['name']));
```

**UPDATE** 302 Found - это ответ перенаправления, по которому браузер спокойно переходит и потому беспроблемно получает доступ к конечному ресурсу. Вы можете сделать то же самое, прочитав заголовок Location в ответе.

Comment: Ошибки исправил, извиняюсь.
Проблема не в заголовках скрипта. 
Сервер по адресу `https://cs1-41v4.vk-cdn.net/` отвечает "**302 Found**", когда из браузера ссылка открывается без проблем.

Comment: @Denel_Manilov обновил

Comment: В заголовке Location ведет на 404ю страницу вида: `https://vk.com/err404.php?path=https://cs1-41v4.vk-cdn.net/p20/b5e45ecd84ac65.mp3?extra=vfY-bFvuPvDSEnlZMYWKBYT6GiwNKWi5VgzqRLIiXnK-6EeYaUg-ypaXG4d4eoVtDafoQTdpsp9gFof2T2nXPztSlKdQ46o,262&from=[МОЙ_IP]&hash=0a6ca97bceff43`

Comment: Это защита от подобных запросов. Без реверс-инженерии не сказать, как она обходится.